# Prometheus sum by rate give crazily high spike

Tags: prometheus, promql

Using PromQL, I can draw two charts, using different time interval.
`sum (rate (some_metrics[1s]))`
`sum (rate (some_metrics[1h]))`
However, for the second chart:
`sum (rate (some_metrics[1h]))`
It sometimes gives a crazily steady high spike
where the `sum (rate (some_metrics[1s]))` behaves normally
Any help is appreciated.

Even weirder, those only happen for roughly an hour. After an hour, then this bizzare spike disappear and it behaves normally again.

Comment: Doubt `sum` has anything to do with problem at hand. Can you validate that rate itself produces unexpected values?

Comment: Also what raw values does `some_metrics` have in your example? Could it be that reset is handled incorrectly? Ir maybe your counter reseted not to 0?

Comment: Thanks! 
Some_metrics is multiple time series under the same metric name.
I don't think it's a issue with reset, because the weird thing is that it's only a issue when I observer THE PREVIOUS ONE HOUR data, and that "uniform high rate of increase" (It's a linear spike with stable rate of change) will disappear after an hour.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much.